# redux-actions Typescript declare an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

At the moment I try to develop my first react & redux and typescript example, but I'm stuck at the declaration of an action. The typescript compiler still throws the same error over and over.

Maybe I missunderstood something of the concept.

The code is based on [this](https://github.com/jaysoo/todomvc-redux-react-typescript) tutorial.

Would be glad about any help

graphActions.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts"/>

import { createAction, Action } from 'redux-actions';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {IGraphObject} from "../components/graph/GraphObject";
import {Graph} from "../models/Graph";
import {ADD_GRAPH} from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const addGraph = createAction<Graph>(
    ADD_GRAPH,
    (graph: IGraphObject) => ({graphObject: graph})
);

export {
    addGraph
}
```

Graph.ts

```
import {IGraphObject} from "../components/graph/GraphObject";

export type Graph = {
    id?: number;
    graphObject: IGraphObject
}
```

GraphObject.ts

```
export interface IGraphObject {
    id?: number;
    graphConfig: IGraphConfig;
    graphInstance: any;
    initGraph(container: HTMLElement);
    addShape(shape: ICustomShapeElement);
}
```

The typescript compiler throws

```
(11,5): error TS2345: Argument of type '(graph: IGraphObject) => { graphObject: IGraphObject; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: { id?: number; graphObject: IGraphObject; }[]) => { id?: number; graphObject: IGraphObj...'.
  Types of parameters 'graph' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id?: number; graphObject: IGraphObject; }' is not assignable to type 'IGraphObject'.
      Property 'graphConfig' is missing in type '{ id?: number; graphObject: IGraphObject; }'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. A look at the redux-actions typings helped me.

**redux-actions typings**

```
export function createAction<Input, Payload>(
      actionType: string,
      payloadCreator?: PayloadCreator<Input, Payload>
): (...args: Input[]) => Action<Payload>;
```

**Solution**

```
const addGraph = createAction<IGraphObject, Graph>(
    ADD_GRAPH,
    (graphObject: IGraphObject) => ({graphObject: graphObject})
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is here:

```
const addGraph = createAction<Graph>(
    ADD_GRAPH,
    (graph: IGraphObject) => ({graphObject: graph})
);
```

You are passing a `IGrapObject` as a parameter of that anonymous function and the expected return value of that function is of type `Graph`.

To make it work your class `Graph` have to implement `IGraphObject`.

But I think that the best would be if you would return Graph, like so:

```
const addGraph = createAction<Graph>(
    ADD_GRAPH,
    (graph: Graph) => ({graphObject: graph})
);
```

Also move the properties `graphConfig` and `graphInstance` to Graph and perhaps change the addShape function so it is a array of `IcustomShapeElement` and add it to the Grap instead.

Does that make sense?

//Daniel

Comment: The graphs for the redux store are a simple type, that should contain the more complex graph-instances. 

What i want to achieve is: User clicks addGraph button => I create a graphObjectInstance and dispatch that to the redux store. Like in the example that it should create a Todo out of a string

Comment: Ok, then I think it should be addGraph = createAction<IGraphObject>, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Solved it. A look at the index.d.ts of redux-actions helped me.


`const addGraph = createAction<IGraphObject, Graph>`